# How to get the entity's ID before persist?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

In my case, the relationship of Article and Block is OneToMany, it means there are many Blocks in one Article. And in Article I use CascadeType.ALL to manage Block, here is the code.

```
@Entity
public class Article implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ARTICLE_ID")
    private List<Block> blocks;

    ...
}
```

And I want to record the order of my Blocks, for performance reason, I decide not to use the index of ArrayList but to set previous Block's id in current Block's priorId, and then persist to the database. see the code below.

```
@Entity
public class Block implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "BLOCK_ID_GEN",
        table = "ENTITY_KEY",
        pkColumnName = "ENTITY_NAME",
        pkColumnValue = "BLOCK",
        valueColumnName = "KEY_SEQUENCE",
        allocationSize = 10)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "BLOCK_ID_GEN")
    private Long id;

    ...

    private Long priorId;

    ...
}

public class BlockUtil {

    public static List<Block> setPriorId(List<Block> blocks) {
        List<Block> resultBlocks = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!blocks.isEmpty()) {
            resultBlocks.add(blocks.get(0));
            for (int i = 1; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
                blocks.get(i).setPriorId(blocks.get(i - 1).getId());
                resultBlocks.add(blocks.get(i));
            }
        }
        return resultBlocks;
    }
}
```

The question is that I can't know Block's id unless I persist them to the database, so what should I do if I insist my approach? Or any better approach I should use? Anyway, I want them in order. Thank you so much!

Comment: since you use "IDENTITY" strategy then that is only assigned WHEN you INSERT. So you cannot get the id before persist! Obviously if you used a different strategy then you could have the "id" before persist ...

Comment: Why do you think that doing this will improve your performance?

Comment: @NeilStockton I then tried the TableGenerator, but still, doesn't work....

Comment: "doesnt work" : really descriptive. TABLE strategy will be set on persist but before INSERT, so you can intercept in prePersist. That is where debugging is involved, rather than saying "doesnt work". Also if you simply expect the "id" to be assigned BEFORE the call to em.persist then kindly explain how JPA would be involved with a class before it is encountered by the JPA API

Comment: @SteveC I mainly consider that if I use ArrayList and there are many records in my data table, every record has a column called INDEX, then I delete one block or move it to another position or create it in a specific position, In some situation it may cause many other records' INDEX be changed, right? But my approach is just like a LinkedList, it will only change some records' INDEX.

Comment: @NeilStockton uh...you're right, I can't explain it. lol. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Either don't use a generator for the id but set the id yourself (for example by using a sequence).
- Or change your model. Instead of associating `block.priorId` with `priorBlock.id`, reason in terms of Object : associate `block.prior` with `priorBlock`. In this way you would not have needed to know the id of the block to associate them.

As a side note, as @Steve C suggested, I have also some difficulties to understand how you will get more speed  :

> And I want to record the order of my Blocks, for performance reason, I
>   decide not to use the index of ArrayList but to set previous Block's
>   id in current Block's priorId,

Comment: I mainly consider that if I use ArrayList and there are many records in my data table, every record has a column called INDEX, then I delete one block or move it to another position or create it in a specific position, In some situation it may cause many other records' INDEX be changed, right? But my approach is just like a LinkedList, it will only change some records' INDEX.

Comment: I understand your need but beware as handling the relation between the elements at two place (the list and your Block instance) constraint you to do these tasks twice : in the list and in your chained objects ... if you don't want your entities be inconsistent. In these conditions, I am not sure that finally you will gain really something.

Comment: Wow, you're right, I should reorder them and then put in a new ArrayList when I retrieve them from the database. Thank you anyway, I should think twice~~